# Match lines that doesn't contains specific pattern and append string in the end - Bash

Tags: bash, perl

I am trying to search a file and append a specific string on the end of every line that doesn't match the specific pattern.

Here is a part of the file:

```
<h3>Release: </h3>

** Commit to create release 
** Add firmware 

<h4>Application changes: </h4>

** Add testfunction <br/>
** Add update support to application<br/>
```

I want to append `<br/>` in the end of every line where it's missing (if it's not a header, so basically any line that doesn't end with >).

I tried matching all the lines that doesn't ends with `> and empty space after that` using `^(?!.*>\s*)` in Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/^(?!.*>\s*)/$&<br\/>/' temp.html > output.html
```

It can find the line, but unfortunately it appends to the beginning of the line even though I appended after the matched line: `$&<br\/>`. I want to append `<br/>` in the end.

My code output:

```
<h3>Release: </h3>

<br/>** Commit to create release 
<br/>** Add firmware 

<h4>Application changes: </h4>

** Add testfunction <br/>
** Add update support to application<br/>
```

My desired output:

```
<h3>Release: </h3>

** Commit to create release <br/>
** Add firmware <br/>

<h4>Application changes: </h4>

** Add testfunction <br/>
** Add update support to application<br/>
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you meant was something like this, using a negative lookbehind assertion:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!\>)$/<br\/>/' temp.html > output.html
```

Note that I've removed the `\s*` - that's because the Perl regular expression engine doesn't support variable-length lookbehind. I'd also note this has problems with empty lines on my system.

How about using something simple using `if` instead?

```
perl -pe 's/$/<br\/>/ if !/\>\s*$/ && !/^\s*$/' temp.html > output.html
```

Comment: I would write `!/^\s*$/` as `/\S/`. Inverting the logic makes it simpler ("the line contains at least one non-whitespace character").

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's#[^>[:space:]]$#<br/>#g' temp.html >output.html
```

- `s`: Is `sed` search and replace command.
- `#`: Is the `sed` command parameters separator.
- `[^>[:space:]]$`: Is search pattern for no `>` or `[:space:]` character at `$` end of line.
- `<br/>`: Is the replacement for the pattern.
- `g`: Tells `sed` to apply the search-replace everywhere in the file.

Comment: This works but it also replaces the empty lines with `<br/>`.

Comment: It does not process empty lines but lines containing spaces.
This is a quick change to the `sed` code then `s#[^>[:space:]]$#<br/>#g`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using sed for this.
The following command will extract the `<br\>` as the first argument, then the rest of the line as the second argument, then swap their places.

```
sed -i -Ee 's/(<br\/>)(.*)/\2\1/g' $file
```

Using `-i` the input is also the output.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately when I apply your code, I don't see any changes. The output file is same with missing `<br\>`.

Comment: Interesting, might be different sed versions. I used `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`